# Retrieve original filename of varbinary image file

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've stored an image in varbinary type in SQL Server.
Here's an example of data:

> 0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000005E7000002DB0802000000FFE6ACCA00000001735247420 (and much more characters after)

Originally, it's filename is : test.jpg

I'd like to retrieve "test.jpg" by a stored procedure in SQL Server instead of this long and terrifying string. Is it possible?

Comment: Not unless you've stored it.

Comment: You need an additional column in the table to store the file name, or any other meta-data  you're interested in - then it's a simple select query.

Answer (score 2):

No.  A file's name is typically only stored in the filesystem; not in the contents of the file. So unless you stored the filename in a separate column, you can't retrieve it with TSQL.